# How to run tasks in parallel using @EnableScheduling

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am following the example from here to run tasks in parallel using `@EnableScheduling` - [from this tutorial](http://websystique.com/spring/spring-job-scheduling-with-scheduled-enablescheduling-annotations/)

Here is my code -

```
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class MyJobScheduler implements SchedulingConfigurer {

  @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
  public Executor taskExecutor() {
    return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
  }

  @Override
  public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
  }

  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype")
  public MyJobExecutor createMyJobExecutor() {
    return new MyJobExecutor();
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void registerServices() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        createMyJobExecutor();
    }
  }
}


public class MyJobExecutor {
private static final Logger logger = 
  LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyJobExecutor.class);

  @Autowired
  MyService myService;

  @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "10000", initialDelayString = "30000")
  public void runJob() {
    try {
        logger.info("MyJobExecutor executing...");
        myService.myJobTask();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(MyJobExecutor failed.", e);
    }
  }
}


@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class MyJobScheduler2 implements SchedulingConfigurer {

  @Bean(destroyMethod="shutdown")
  public Executor taskExecutor() {
    return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
  }

  @Override
  public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
  }

  @Bean
  @Scope("prototype")
  public MyJobExecutor2 createMyJobExecutor() {
    return new MyJobExecutor2();
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void registerServices() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        createMyJobExecutor();
    }
  }
}

public class MyJobExecutor2 {
  private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyJobExecutor2.class);

  @Autowired
  MyService2 myService;

  @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "10000", initialDelayString = "30000")
  public void runJob() {
    try {
        logger.info("MyJobExecutor2 executing...");
        myService.myJobTask();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(MyJobExecutor2 failed.", e);
    }
  }
}
```

When I have just one scheduler configured, MyJobScheduler, I get the expected number of jobs running in parallel. However, I need 2 scheduled jobs. When I add MyJobScheduler2, here are the logs...

> 21:03:25.291 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.p.MyJobExecutor2 - MyJobExecutor2 executing...
>   21:03:25.459 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.p.MyJobExecutor2 - MyJobExecutor2 executing...
>   21:03:25.537 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.p.MyJobExecutor - MyJobExecutor executing...
>   21:03:25.680 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO  c.t.m.e.s.e.p.p.MyJobExecutor - MyJobExecutor executing...

I was expecting MyJobScheduler to use 5 threads and MyJobScheduler2 to use 2 threads. It seems like both these Schedulers are using the same thread pool and getting limited to 2 threads rather than getting their own separate thread pools. What can be going on here?

Comment: Why should they execute in parallel? They are scheduled each `200ms` it isn't a long running task so each can use the same thread. Apparently the thread pool returns the same thread each time because it it available.

Comment: M. Denium - I guess I was expecting the scheduled job to run in parallel to speed up the execution of the overall processing of what the job does. Is there a way to run these scheduled jobs simultaneously? I have made sure that the job is thread-safe.

Comment: Why... The job isn't doing anything more, apparently, then doing a `System.out`... Why should it run in parallel it finishes within the time it takes to start a new one... Then what would be the purpose ... There are no concurrently running tasks and thus no multiple threads.

Comment: M. Denium - The output you are seeing is the same thread processing a bunch of messages from an api call and updating the DB. They are not from separate executions of the job...I should have explained this a little better before. What I would like to do is have the job run multiple threads simultaneously so that each can process separate set of messages and make DB updates at the same time...hence speeding up overall execution of what the job does. Does this make more sense?

Comment: That is something completely different then scheduling. You are confusing/mxing things. Also that isn't what your question is about, so I would suggest rewrite your question.

Comment: M. Deinum - I made some progress with the above issue. I was able to run multiple instances of the job however getting some odd behavior when I add another scheduler. Somehow both schedulers are using the same thread pool.

Comment: Because there only is one scheduler. They are both named `taskScheduler` so only 1 will remain (one overrides the other). Also multiple schedulers won't work as there isn't a way to specify which scheduler to use for which annotation.

Comment: Yes, I already tried 3 things to separate the schedulers - renamed the taskExecutor(), I added @ComponentScan to specify exactly which classes the configuration is meant for and I also tried getting rid of the Executor bean and directly created the thread pools in taskRegistrar.setScheduler() within overriden method configureTasks. Nothing made a difference. They still shared the same thread pool.

Comment: As I already stated you cannot use different scheduler pools as there is no way of specifying which to use in the `@Scheduled` annotation.